# How can I loop through a directory and get wc of every txt file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

The shell is sh.

I have been using a for loop:

```
for F in *.txt
do
echo `wc -w $F`
done
```

This has been returning the number of words and the name of the file. I don't understand why it keeps returning the name of the file; it looks like it should only return the number of words in the file.

Comment: `man wc` is your friend.

Comment: Using `echo` is redundant; just use `wc -w "$F"`.

Answer (score 10):

This is the default behavior of `wc`, it shows the filename after the count.

If you just want the count, pass the filename via STDIN:

```
wc -w <filename
```

Also, without iterating over the files using `for`, you could just use globbing for getting the filenames at once, `wc` takes multiple arguments so there would not be a problem:

```
wc -w *.txt
```

In this case, to get rid of the filenames, use some text-processing:

```
wc -w *.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

This should be faster than the `for`a approach you have already.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you